# Category with "all equalisers"

Tags: category-theory

I have an easy question. Is there a thing called "a category has all equalisers"? Having all finite products I have heard of but having all equalisers I haven't. Am I totally misinterpreting something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is, and it precisely means what you think it would mean. All parallel pairs of arrows have an equalizer. Or, in other words, the category has all limits of the type given by the index category with two objects, and two distinct morphisms from one of the objects to the other.